# Slow runtime when objects are passed by value vs when passed by reference

Tags: c++, graph, vector, constructor

This is a constructor for a class called `Graph`. In the constructor I am trying to initialise somethings and here is the contructor that works i.e. it runs and finishes:

```
Graph(const float density, const int numVertex = 50): numEdges(0) {
        graph.resize(numVertex, vector<Vertex>(numVertex));
        for (int s = 0; s < numVertex; ++s) {
            for (int k = 0; k < s; ++k )
                if (edge_exist(density)) {
                    graph[s][k].visited = graph[k][s].visited = false;
                    graph[s][k].distance = graph[k][s].distance = _MAX;
                    ++numEdges;
                    int distance = rand() % 10 + 1;
                    graph[s][k].edges.emplace_back(piiv(distance, graph[k][s]));
                    graph[k][s].edges.emplace_back(piiv(distance, graph[s][k]));
                }
        }       
    }
typedef pair<int, Vertex> piiv;
vector<vector<Vertex> > graph;
```

The class has a field called `graph` which is a vector of vector of struct called `Vertex`.

```
typedef struct vert {
    std::list<std::pair<int, vert> > edges;
    int distance;
    bool visited;
} Vertex;
```

Now if I leave the vertex struct the way it is and instead make the vector just a one dimensional vector

```
vector<Vertex> graph;
```

And change the constructor to be like so:

```
Graph(const float density, const int numVertex = 50): numEdges(0) {
        graph.resize(numVertex);
        for (int s = 0; s < numVertex; ++s) {
            for (int k = 0; k < s; ++k )
                if (edge_exist(density)) {
                    graph[s].visited = graph[k].visited = false;
                    graph[s].distance = graph[k].distance = _MAX;
                    ++numEdges;
                    int distance = rand() % 10 + 1;
                    graph[s].edges.emplace_back(piiv(distance, graph[k]));
                    graph[k].edges.emplace_back(piiv(distance, graph[s]));
                }
        }       
    }
```

Now this change causes the code to run far longer than it usually does when the vector was 2 dimensional. I have not had the patience to figure out how long it runs, but I know it runs unreasonably slower than the first one and for no apparent reason. Well not apparent to me, but I bet someone here has some insight as to why this is.

So my question is, what is causing this seemingly unnecessary delay in the program?
If it helps, this is how the constructor is called:

```
Graph G(0.4);
```

I have tracked the problem to be coming from these last 2 lines in the second constructor implementation:

```
graph[s].edges.emplace_back(piiv(distance, graph[k]));
graph[k].edges.emplace_back(piiv(distance, graph[s]));
```

So I guess the real question is how is the above different from what is being done in the first constructor?

### EDIT

**Bingo!**
As I was debugging I decided to change the Vertex struct to be declared like so:

```
typedef struct vert {
    std::list<std::pair<int, vert&> > edges;
    int distance;
    bool visited;
} Vertex;
```

This seemed to fix the problem, but why?? Why is passing in the Vertex object by value not working as compared to pass by reference?

Comment: With `std::pair<int, vert>`, you'd be copying in the entire target, as opposed to referring to it.  And since `vert` contains a list of edges, it would copy that, which would copy all those `vert`... turtles all the way down!  If you want to see how much fun the compiler was having, define a copy constructor for the original `vert` that does the copy, but also prints out that it's doing so.  It may surprise you.  `pair<int, vert>` is wrong for other reasons:  if you ever change the target vertex, the edge won't see the change, because it has a private copy of the `vert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this was happening was nicely summarized by [@Joe Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2354107/joe-z).

```
std::list<std::pair<int, vert> > edges;
```

By declaring the `Vertex` edges to be a list of other that contains other `Vertex` *by value*, this meant that each time a new vertex is added to the list, the copy constructor immediately kicks in and starts making a copy of all of that `vert`'s edges which also means making a copy of all any children of that `Vertex` and so on and so forth...

As you can see, this insatiable copying means that as the graph gets denser, we the copying takes progressively more time and God help us if we decide to introduce a cycle in the graph because this means we will run out of memory before this program finishes.

Changing the `edges` property to have this type:

```
std::list<std::pair<int, vert&> > edges;
```

Now this means that each time we add a new edge to the graph, we simply maintain a reference to the other vertices rather than copying them. This also means we can actually be able to detect when an edge has been removed from another vertex.

Furthermore, I would actually define this edge to be:

```
std::list<std::pair<int, const vert&> > edges;
```

This is just a matter of good practice because we want to ensure that edges are immutable and having a reference to another vertex does not mean being able to change it's properties.